# Angle constraint doesn't work for certain angles

Tags: java, math, 2d, physics, game-physics

I'm writing an angle joint for my 2d physics engine. It works, except for when the max angle is negative and the min angle is positive (when the angle is directly to the left).

As you can see, all of the other balls move within their tolerance angle, but the one directly to the left does not.

[image: 6 angle joints connected to the center]

```
public class AngleJoint extends Joint {

    private float minAngle;
    private float maxAngle;

    public AngleJoint(
        final GameEntity a, 
        final GameEntity b, 
        final float midAngle, 
        final float tolerance
    ) {
        super(a, b);
        assert tolerance >= 0;
        minAngle = midAngle - tolerance;
        maxAngle = midAngle + tolerance;

        while (minAngle > Math.PI) {
            minAngle -= 2 * Math.PI;
        }
        while (minAngle < -Math.PI) {
            minAngle += 2 * Math.PI;
        }
        while (maxAngle > Math.PI) {
            maxAngle -= 2 * Math.PI;
        }
        while (maxAngle < -Math.PI) {
            maxAngle += 2 * Math.PI;
        }
        System.out.println(minAngle + ", " + maxAngle);
    }

    @Override
    public void update() {
        assert getA() != null && getB() != null;

        final CManifold m = new CManifold();
        m.a = getA();
        m.b = getB();

        final Vec2D aToB = getB().center().minus(getA().center());
        // angle from A to B
        final float angle = aToB.getTheta();

        if (angle >= minAngle && angle <= maxAngle) {
            // we don't need to do anything
            return;
        }

        final float distBtoA = aToB.length();

        final float closestAngleBound 
            = Math.abs(angle - maxAngle) < Math.abs(angle - minAngle) 
            ? maxAngle : minAngle;

        // where we should be
        final Vec2D solvedLocation 
            = getA().center().plus(
                new Vec2D((float) (
                    Math.cos(closestAngleBound) * distBtoA), 
                    (float) (Math.sin(closestAngleBound) * distBtoA)
                )
            );
        final Vec2D correction = solvedLocation.minus(getB().center());
        final float d = correction.length();

        m.setNormal(correction.divide(d));
        m.setPenetration(d);
        Collisions.fixCollision(m, false);
    }

}
```

This is where I create this particular scene.

```
final Vec2D centerV = new Vec2D(500, 700);

    center = createBall(centerV, 75);
    center.setMass(GameEntity.INFINITE_MASS);
    entities.add(center);

    final float vertices = 6;
    final float dist = 120;

    GameEntity first = null;
    GameEntity last = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < vertices; i++) {
        final float angle = (float) (2 * Math.PI / vertices * i);
        final Vec2D newCenter 
            = new Vec2D(
                (float) (centerV.x + Math.cos(angle) * dist), 
                (float) (centerV.y + Math.sin(angle) * dist)
            );
        final GameEntity vertex = createBall(newCenter, 10);
        entities.add(vertex);
        if (last != null) {
            // constraints.add(new DistanceJoint(last, vertex));
        } else {
            first = vertex;
        }
        constraints.add(new DistanceJoint(center, vertex));
        constraints.add(new AngleJoint(center, vertex, angle, .1f));
        last = vertex;
        if (i == vertices - 1 && first != null) {
            // constraints.add(new DistanceJoint(first, vertex));
        }
    }
}
```

How can I fix my update method so that the ball to the left behaves similarly to the other ones?

Comment: @durron597 Yeah, I just committed it.

Comment: I've given up on trying to figure this out. It's hard to figure out what is happening; your classes are too tightly coupled and your methods are too long. I recommend reading [**How to debug small programs**](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and learn how to use JUnit and Mockito.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem by first implementing a check that [Warren Dew](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32001178/2731457) suggested, but also changing a bit of my math. This is the finished joint class

```
public class AngleJoint extends Joint {

    // angles stored between -Pi and Pi
    private final float minAngle;
    private final float maxAngle;

    /**
     *
     * @param a
     * @param b
     * @param midAngle
     *            the angle in the range of -Pi to Pi.
     * @param tolerance
     *            the angle tolerance in both directions. 0 <= tolerance < Pi
     */
    public AngleJoint(final GameEntity a, final GameEntity b, final float midAngle, final float tolerance) {
        super(a, b);
        if (tolerance < 0 || tolerance >= AngleUtils.PI) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Tolerance must be >= 0 and < Pi");
        }
        minAngle = AngleUtils.normalize(midAngle - tolerance);
        maxAngle = AngleUtils.normalize(midAngle + tolerance);
    }

    @Override
    public void update() {
        assert getA() != null && getB() != null;

        final CManifold m = new CManifold();
        m.a = getA();
        m.b = getB();

        final Vec2D aToB = getB().center().minus(getA().center());
        // angle from A to B
        final float angle = aToB.getTheta();

        if (angle >= minAngle && angle <= maxAngle) {
            // we don't need to do anything
            return;
        }
        // if we are in that dumb spot where maxAngle < min Angle (directly to the left) we need extra checks
        if (maxAngle < minAngle && (angle <= maxAngle && angle >= -AngleUtils.PI || angle >= minAngle && angle <= AngleUtils.PI)) {
            return;
        }

        final float distBtoA = aToB.length();

        final float closestAngleBound = AngleUtils.angleDifference(angle, maxAngle) < AngleUtils.angleDifference(angle, minAngle) ? maxAngle
                : minAngle;

        // where we should be
        final Vec2D solvedLocation = getA().center().plus(
                new Vec2D((float) (Math.cos(closestAngleBound) * distBtoA), (float) (Math.sin(closestAngleBound) * distBtoA)));
        final Vec2D correction = solvedLocation.minus(getB().center());
        final float d = correction.length();

        m.setNormal(correction.divide(d));
        m.setPenetration(d);
        Collisions.fixCollision(m, false);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

This part of the code:

```
    if (angle >= minAngle && angle <= maxAngle) {
        // we don't need to do anything
        return;
    }
```

never causes a return for the angle in question; since maxAngle is negative and minAngle is positive, angle can never be both greater than a positive minAngle and less than a negative maxAngle.

As a result, even when the angle is between the two limits, execution for this joint falls through to the part where, it looks like, the angle is forced towards the closest limit.  Since it's forced to the closest limit, it can't bounce freely between the limits.

You need some special case code to replace the quoted test above for cases where maxAngle is negative and minAngle is positive.  You might have to fix other things too, but that would be a start.

Comment: I appreciate the response, I did have to implement a check like you suggested